# Django looking for wrong path for template file

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, deployment, django-templates

**My django project works in localhost perfectly.**
And i was trying to deploy it on Ubuntu-Apache.
I did git clone

And i got this error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
```

Hum ? and i pay attention to this error message

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /templates/base_layout.html (Source does not exist)
```

This Error came from

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html'%} (/home/ubuntu/django/blog/djangonautic/articles/templates/articles/article_list.html)
```

I hoped Django to search templates in the parent folder ({root}/templates).

The right path of it is

```
/home/ubuntu/django/blog/djangonautic/templates/base_layout.html
```

(File is there i checked)

Why my Django dosen't looking for it in (root) templates ?

in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates', 'front/build'],
...
```

**I Guess it is because.**

1. Virtualenv
   I created this in Ubuntu (didn't created in local)
2. Apache configure
   I was following https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/ec2apachedjango-838e3f6014ab this post.
3. something wrong in settings.py
   But i don't think this is wrong cause in local it works well...

Tell me anything you need to debugging i will answer quickly

**SOLVED**
Add `os.path.join` and works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
```

I don't think you should leave out the BASE_DIR setting in your templates setting?

Comment: It works! but would you tell me why it is works in local window   i don't know what i am missing about 'os.path'

Comment: The point is, if you put it without BASE_DIR, Django cannot found it because your hosted project is likely to be a lot higher than the base directory. If you didn't add the base directory, Django don't know where to look for it as it can't go out of the directory where your manage.py is located.